# Tkinter spinbox textvariable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple GUI in Tkinter to display some xy data. The data's arranged in trials and the goal is to have a spinbox that allows you to select which trial to view. I don't understand why but in the code below the value of the textvariable is not updated and so I always end up viewing the same trial. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? The code follows. The Tk.IntVar gets set in the **init**, gets associated with the spinbox (very bottom) and gets used in the updateDataToPlot.

```
#graphing stuff
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import Tkinter as Tk

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import randn
from collections import defaultdict

class DataPlotter:
    def __init__(self, ax, data):

        self.ax = ax
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.data = data

        self.xRaw = []
        self.yRaw = []

        self.lineRaw = Line2D(self.xRaw, self.yRaw, animated=True, marker = None, color = 'black')
        self.ax.add_line(self.lineRaw)

        self.background = None
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.updateBackground)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-3,3)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-3,3)

        self.ax.set_xlabel('X Pos (mm)')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Y Pos (mm)')

        self.TrialNum = Tk.IntVar()
        self.TrialNum.set(0)

    def updateBackground(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)

    def updateDataToPlot(self):
        trialNum = self.TrialNum.get()
        print trialNum

        self.xRaw = self.data['polaris_rawPositions'][trialNum][:,0]
        self.yRaw = self.data['polaris_rawPositions'][trialNum][:,1]

        self.updateView()

    def updateView(self):
        if self.background is None: return True

        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)

        self.lineRaw.set_data(self.xRaw, self.yRaw)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.lineRaw)

        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)

data = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(100):
    data['polaris_rawPositions'].append(randn(200,2))

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Data Explorer")

f = Figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.show()

Plotter = DataPlotter(ax, data)

spinbox = Tk.Spinbox(master=root, textvariable = Plotter.TrialNum, command = Plotter.updateDataToPlot, fg= 'black', from_ = 0, to = 100, increment = 1)
spinbox.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, anchor='e', padx = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

i tested here the tk.spinbox and worked perfectly as your layout, just checked your code aren't you getting any exception?

```
#self.data = '/data/data', is this right?
#'/data/data'['polaris_rawPositions']
#also [:,0] using period, should use dots [:.0]
self.xRaw = self.data['polaris_rawPositions'][trialNum][:,0]
```

also for debug porpuse try putting one print there, so you can check the value

```
trialNum = self.TrialNum.get()
print(trialNum)
```

sorry if I'm missing something, I really never touched the matplotlib module.

Comment: The '/data/data' is a placeholder for the message/post. On my computer it's a real dictionary, full of numpy arrays. I've done the print(trialNum) and it always gives me 0 (or whatever I set the initial value of the variable to). The commas are correct for numpy indexing. Hmmm

Comment: example looks OK here. What platform are you on?